# Корректная работа со связующей таблицей, состоящей более чем из двух внешних ключей?

Tags: php, база-данных, laravel

У меня есть несколько моделей в приложении: работы (`Work`), запчасти (`Part`) и этапы (`Step`). Для того чтобы знать на каком этапе и для какой запчасти применяются работы есть таблица `part_step_work`, в ней содержаться только 3 поля, и все 3 поля являются внешними ключами на таблицы тех моделей, что я перечислил выше. Вопрос - как вы поступаете в данной ситуации? Ниже мои варианты:

**1.** Оставляете только внешние ключи и не создаёте автоинкрементное поле `id`. Далее работа происходит только через связь `belongsToMany` с заданием условия `wherePivot` для третьего поля. Т.е. в каждой модели будет описано поведение для выбора связей. Пример для модели `Part`:

```php
/**
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
 */
public function works() :\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Models\Repair\Work::class, 'part_step_work', 'partId', 'workId')
        ->withPivot('stepId');
}

/**
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
 */
public function steps() :\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Models\Repair\Step::class, 'part_step_work', 'partId', 'stepId')
        ->withPivot('workId');
}

/**
 * @param \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|int $step
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
 */
public function worksOfStep($step) :\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
{
    $step = ($step instanceof \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model) ? $step->getKey() : $step;

    return $this->works()->wherePivot('stepId', $step);
}
```

Стоит учесть, что при создании новых моделей также придется каждый раз прописывать доп. атрибуты для `pivot` полей. Например - `$this->works()->attach(1, ['stepId' => 1])`.

**2**. Создаёте PK и работаете со связью `hasMany` для каждой модели. Пример для `Part`:

```
/**
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
 */
public function worksOnSteps() :\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(\App\Models\Pivot\PartStepWork::class, 'partId');
}
```

Comment: Если я знаю, что мне придется управлять сущностью, я всегда делаю ей уникальный ID.

Comment: @ilyaplot но если данная таблица используется только для связки и дальнейшего доступа к моделям через неё? Проблема в том, что если я последую варианту 2, то чтобы получить все работы на этапе 1 для детали 1 нужно будет проходится циклом по всем worksOnSteps и оттуда вытаскивать отношение works, которое будет являться belongTo. Оправданы ли эти действия?